# Cannot seem to make my player jump in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm working on a 2D game in Unity attempting to make my player jump. Despite watching tons of videos and adjusting the code many times, he simply won't jump when I press the space bar. After even checking the input manager in Unity, I'm sure it's a simple fix I'm missing somewhere but I don't see where it could be.

```
public class FoxyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d; 
    float horizontal;
    float vertical; 
    public float jumpVelocity = 10f; 

void Start()
{
    rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}


void Update()
{
    horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    { 
        Jump(); 
    }
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 position= rigidbody2d.position;
    position.x = position.x + 4f * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;
    position.y = position.y + 4f * vertical * Time.deltaTime; 

    rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);         
}

void Jump()
{
    rigidbody2d.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpVelocity; 
}
```

}

Comment: Yeah I would use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html instead of modifying the velocity directly. And I think your issue is caused by your FixedUpdate, which may be overriding the velocity change from the jump function because horizontal or vertical might be 0 depending on input settings (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use  -> rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpAmount, ForceMode2D.Impulse); where jumpAmount can be multiplayer, you can use 10f as jumpAmount value.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    { 
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpAmount, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

Add Above code in update method instead of jump() method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've tried adding that but it doesn't seem to work. Others have said it's because of my code for movement in FixedUpdate that is not allowing the jump to happen but I'm not too sure how to work around that.

Comment: @lordoftheshire delete the "FixedUpdate" method completely and paste the above method in update function https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-jump-in-unity-with-or-without-physics/ refer this page for more info.